# BeanManager#resolveは何のために使用するか

Tags: java, java-ee

JavaEEの`BeanManager`を使うと、手動でBeanのインスタンスを取得できますが、その方法について疑問があります。
いくつかの解説記事を見たところ、大枠として次のようなコードでインスタンスを取得するらしいことが分かりました。

```
Set<Bean<?>> beans = beanManager.getBeans(Hoge.class);
Bean<?> bean = this.beanManager.resolve(beans);
Object instance = beanManager.getReference(bean, Hoge.class, beanManager.createCreationalContext(bean));
Hoge hoge = (Hoge) instance;
```

ここで、2行目の`BeanManager#resolve`は何をしているのでしょうか？
次の書き方と比べて、何が異なりますか？

```
Bean<?> bean = beans.stream().findFirst().get();
```

派生クラスがあった場合に何かあるのか？　とも考えましたが、だとしても何を以って`Set`から1つだけ取り出すのか分かりません。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Weldの実装](https://github.com/weld/core/blob/master/impl/src/main/java/org/jboss/weld/manager/BeanManagerImpl.java#L1152)を見るのが早いかと思いますが、候補が1つに絞れる場合(すなわちbeansのsizeが1の場合)には、mok2pokさんが質問文に記載されているコードと全く同じ結果となりますね。

BeanManagerImpl:

```
public <X> Bean<? extends X> resolve(Set<Bean<? extends X>> beans) {
    if (beans == null || beans.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    Set<Bean<? extends X>> resolvedBeans = beanResolver.resolve(beans);
    if (resolvedBeans.size() == 1) {
        return resolvedBeans.iterator().next();
    [後略]
```

AbstractTypeSafeBeanResolver:

```
public <X> Set<Bean<? extends X>> resolve(Set<Bean<? extends X>> beans) {
    if (beans.size() <= 1) {
        return beans;
    }
    [後略]
```

> 派生クラスがあった場合に何かあるのか？　とも考えましたが、だとしても何を以ってSetから1つだけ取り出すのか分かりません。

候補が複数ある場合には例外AmbiguousResolutionExceptionが、1つもない場合にはnullが返ります(ので、何らかの情報で対象を1つに絞るような処理を行うわけではありません)。
参考: [BeanManager.html#resolve(java.util.Set) javadoc](https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/api/1.2/javax/enterprise/inject/spi/BeanManager.html#resolve(java.util.Set))

本題の「何のために使用するか」についてですが、上記から分かる通り、質問文中のようなコード中で用いる意味は無いです。
(じゃあなぜそんなメソッドが存在するのか…？という点については、パッケージ名からも読み取れますがBeanManagerはそもそもSPI(Service Provider Interface)[(参考)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954372/)に分類されるものであり、その性質を考えればresolveメソッドにも存在意義ある、というのが想像できるのではないかと。)